# A differential operator of differential operators

Tags: differential-operators

Consider a differential operator of the form $x^2-2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, where $x$ itself is the laplacian.

Does such an operator make sense? The motivation for this is that such an object is naturally coming up in my research, and I want to make sure that something like this even makes sense.

Comment: Could you briefly sketch how this formal expression arises?

Comment: I haven't dealt with the Laplacian in such a role, but in umbral calculus the Pincherle derivative deals with operator commutators of the form $[f(L),R] = f(L)R-Rf(L) = f'(L) = \frac{d}{dL}f(L)$ where $f$ is a somewhat arbitrary analytic function, $L = \sum_{n \geq 1}{a_n} \frac{d^n}{dz^n}$ is the lowering operator for a sequence of Sheffer polynomials, and $R= (z+g(d/dz))h(d/dz)$ is the typically more complicated associated raising op, involving functions $g$ and $h$ dependent on the Sheffer sequence. So, your idea seems plausible.